# Running a query using multiple junction tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table listing case studies and another table that list outcomes.  A case study can have multiple outcomes so I created a junction table.
I want to run a SQL that will show the case once and each of the outcomes so far I have

```
SELECT caseSummaries.caseTitle, caseSummaries.caseSynopsis, RESULTS.resultText
FROM JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY
JOIN caseSummaries ON JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY.caseSummary_FK = caseSummaries.caseID
JOIN RESULTS ON JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY.result_FK = RESULTS.result_ID
GROUP BY caseSummaries.caseID;
```

which gives me one row and only the first outcome of three. How can I show the others in the same row? Will I have to create temporary tables and how is that done?  So far I have used a LEFT JOIN but I still get one row. If I don't use GROUP BY I get the caseSummaries.caseTitle repeated thrice and the outcome for each listed. I want to get the case summary once and each outcome appear in a new column.
Thanks,
C

Assume from the question I have two tables

Case studies with three fields:

- ID
- Title
- Synopsis

and another table containing Outcomes:
[bullet]

- Apology
- Compensation
- Policy change

There is a many to many relationship and my SQL needs to show the outcomes for each case study like this:

Case 1 | Title | Synopsis | Apology|Compensation|Policy change
Case 2 |Title | Synopsis |  Apology|NULL|Policy change

assuming the Case 2 only has 2 outcomes. 
At the moment without the **GROUP BY** or **SELECT DISTINCT**  I get

Case 1 | Title | Synopsis | Apology
Case 1 | Title | Synopsis |Compensation
Case 1 | Title | Synopsis |Policy change
Case 2 | Title | Synopsis | Apology
Case 2 | Title | Synopsis |Policy change

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Just made some changes to the question to include a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function should do what you need:

```
SELECT   caseSummaries.caseTitle, 
         caseSummaries.caseSynopsis, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(RESULTS.resultText)
FROM     JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY
JOIN     caseSummaries ON JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY.caseSummary_FK = caseSummaries.caseID
JOIN     RESULTS ON JNCT_RESULT_CASESUMMARY.result_FK = RESULTS.result_ID
GROUP BY caseSummaries.caseTitle, caseSummaries.caseSynopsis;
```

Comment: Awesome. I've got an extra table to add to this but I will build on this one first. Might be a nested query but who knows

Comment: Looks like I might need a bit more help. Will the group_CONCAT work with an extra junction table in a similar fashion?